# How to generify my interface

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ProvidersFilter {
    void setQuery(@NonNull Object query);

    Object apply();
}
```

And the following implementing classes:

First implementation:

```
public class ProvidersRemoteFilter implements ProvidersFilter {

    private Query mQuery;

    @Override
    public void setQuery(@NonNull Object query) {
        if (query instanceof Query) {
            mQuery = (Query) query;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("query object must be of type com.google.firebase.firestore.Query");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object apply() {
        return mQuery;
    }
}
```

Second implementation:

```
public class ProvidersLocalFilter implements ProvidersFilter {

    private String mQuery;

    @Override
    public void setQuery(@NonNull Object query) {
        if (query instanceof String) {
            mQuery = (String) query;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("query object must be of type String");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object apply() {
        return mQuery;
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid using `instanceof` by generifying my interface and implementing classes.

Comment: `interface ProvidersFilter<Q> { void setQuery(Q query); Q apply(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a type variable to your interface.

Interface:

```
public interface ProvidersFilter<T> {
    void setQuery(@NonNull T query);

    T apply();
}
```

Implementing class:

```
public class ProvidersRemoteFilter implements ProvidersFilter<Query> {

    private Query mQuery;

    @Override
    public void setQuery(@NonNull Query query) {
        mQuery = query;
    }

    @Override
    public Query apply() {
        return mQuery;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since local and remote Providers have the same code you could have an abstract class that implements the commonalities. In that case there is no need for the interface but you can keep it all the same:

```
public interface ProvidersFilter<Q> {
    void setQuery(@NonNull Q query);
    Q apply();
}

abstract class AbstractProvidersFilter<Q> {
    private Q mQuery;

    @Override
    public void setQuery(@NonNull Q query) {
        mQuery = query;
    }

    @Override
    public Q apply() {
        return mQuery;
    }
}

public class ProvidersRemoteFilter extends AbstractProvidersFilter<Query> {}
public class ProvidersLocalFilter extends AbstractProvidersFilter<String> {}
```